# Перевести программу с Pascal'a на С++

Tags: pascal, c++

Помогите, пожалуйста, перевести программу с Pascal'a на С++, буду очень признателен!

```
Users Crt;
Var
     Year, n: Word;
Begin
     ClrScr;
     Write ('Enter Year: ');
     ReadLn (Year);

     n := abs (Year - 1900) mod 12;

Case n Of
     0: WriteLn ('Rat');
     1: WriteLn ('Cow');
     2: WriteLn ('Tiger');
     3: WriteLn ('Rabbit');
     4: WriteLn ('Dragon');
     5: WriteLn ('Snake');
     6: WriteLn ('Horse');
     7: WriteLn ('Sheep');
     8: WriteLn ('Monkey');
     9: WriteLn ('Cock');
     10: WriteLn ('Dog');
     11: WriteLn ('Pig');
Else
     TextColor (lightred);
      Write ('Year entered incorrectly.');
end;

ReadKey;
End.
```

Comment: А что, до 1900 года "животные" шли в обратном порядке? (я про abs)

Comment: ребят, я не вкурсе

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int Year, n;
void main ()
{
    clrscr ();
    printf ("Enter Year: ");
    scanf ("%i", &Year);

    n = abs (Year - 1900) % 12;

    switch (n)
    {
        case 0: printf ("Rat"); break;
        case 1: printf ("Cow"); break;
        case 2: printf ("Tiger"); break;
        case 3: printf ("Rabbit"); break;
        case 4: printf ("Dragon"); break;
        case 5: printf ("Snake"); break;
        case 6: printf ("Horse"); break;
        case 7: printf ("Sheep"); break;
        case 8: printf ("Monkey"); break;
        case 9: printf ("Cock"); break;
        case 10: printf ("Dog"); break;
        case 11: printf ("Pig"); break;
        default:
        textcolor (RED);

        cprintf ("Year entered incorrectly.");
    }
    getch ();
}
```

Comment: благодарю за быстрый ответ я даже не ожидал :)

Comment: Не за что.

Comment: @Ковальский, где здесь C++?

Comment: @deterok, Я конечно извиняюсь, а что не так?

Comment: @Ковальский,  deterok имел ввиду что тут нету С++ только чистый С, в С++ был бы iostream.h, using namespace std, и <<, >>.

Comment: @ProkletyPirat iostream.h уже давно в могиле. must be iostream:

    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    using namespace std;
    int main() {
      int year;
      string beasts[] = {"Rat", "Cow", "Tiger", "Rabbit", "Dragon", "Snake", "Horse", "Sheep", "Monkey", "Cock", "Dog", "Pig"};
      cout << "Enter year: ";
      cin >> year;
      cout << beasts [abs(year - 1900) % 12] << endl;
    }

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat и @deterok да всё норм, не грузите парня!! мою прогу приняли